# Double dots in the dotplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need help with understanding how can I correct the double dots in my plot.
This is my code:

```
ggplot(AM138_141, aes(x=Worm_Names, y=Length))+ geom_boxplot()+geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = 1, dotsize = 1, position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2), binwidth = 1) +theme_classic()
```

And that is what it makes:
[image]

You can see the small dots - they correct, and bigger dots on the edges, I understand that the program makes double dots from dots that go outside of SD. But how I can fix it?
Thank you for help!

Comment: You could try with `geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA)` to "remove" the outliers or you set their size via `outlier.size = ...`.

Comment: Also `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, both ways are working well!